# How to set up properly resource pools in VMWare ESXi?

Tags: vmware, esxi

How to set up properly resource pools in VMWare ESXi? Does anyone have any blog entries etc.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign up for a VMworld Account and watch the videos from [VMworld 2007](http://www.vmworld.com/community/sessions/2007)

Particularly IO20 and IO21.  You have to have an account to view, and the direct links are a little flaky.